# Multi-platform project with localized cstrings. Can't use cStringUsingEncoding with NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, cstring

I'm trying to replace the var below with an attributed string (needs to be linkable and different color). Apparently you can't use `cStringUsingEncoding` with an `NSMutableAttributedString`? Any options that don't require me to insert the string as a basic string and then match and replace with the attributed version?

```
//"notification_connectionsent_message" = "%1$s wants to connect with you.";

[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"notification_connectionsent_message", @"<User> wants to connect with you"), [fromName cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Thanks

Comment: The posted code has nothing to do with `NSMutableAttributedString`.

Comment: Apologies - fromName is an attributed string.

Comment: `cStringUsingEncoding` is a method of `NSString`, not `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: Have you tried `[[fromName string] cStringUsingEncoding]`?